# Artifact during this STFT spectrogram plotting

Tags: fft, spectrogram, stft

I am new to the field of DSP and I am currently working on implementing a real-time audio spectrogram using STFT technique.
While making progress, I have encountered an issue when testing a constant sine wave at approximately 294Hz (this happens in other frequencies too, this example is specifically during this frequency).
The resulting spectrogram should display a straight line over the frequency bin corresponding to D. However, I am observing a sporadic temporal artifact instead (refer to the provided image).

Although there could be several factors contributing to this artifact, I am seeking insights or potential explanations from the community. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in understanding why this phenomenon may be occurring.

For reference, here are the audio parameters I have used:

```
Sample rate: 44100 Hz
Decimations: 5
Sample size: 512
Window function: Nuttall
Bin size: 8192
```

Thank you.

[image: Artifact during 294Hz sine wave]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  That doesn't seem correct (which is why the question is asked).  How is the D being generated? It looks like a low frequency chirp modulation on top of the base note.

Comment: How close is you D to 294 Hz ?   Could the problem be caused by the fact that 294 exactly divides the sampling rate of 44100 ?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, found out the issue was due to the Android emulator. For some reason, it introduces that artifact. Tried it on a real device and it doesn't happen, the line stays straight.

The D is being generated from this website: https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/ I'm just using a microphone to get it.

Thank you so much!